# Style does not work stably when using Expo and NativeBase

Tags: react-native, expo, native-base

I developing my app with `Expo` and `NativeBase`.

Now this time, I would like you to help me with this weird Style problem.

### Environment

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.3.1",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.10",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.6.1",
    "babel-plugin-dotenv-import": "^2.2.0",
    "expo": "~44.0.0",
    "expo-location": "~14.0.1",
    "expo-permissions": "~13.1.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.2.0",
    "native-base": "^3.3.11",
    "prettier": "^2.6.2",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "0.64.3",
    "react-native-maps": "0.29.4",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.3.2",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.10.1",
    "react-native-svg": "12.1.1",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.1",
    "tailwind-rn": "^4.2.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.0.23"
  },
```

### Example

As I wrote above, Style dose not work stably for any reasons and it's the problem.
I will show you my example.

- **Expected Style**

  This picture is my expected view in this case.
  What I want do is placing the white box that has texts and buttons inside on the center of the `MapView`.

  [image: Screen Shot 2022-04-27 at 21 08 54]
- **Actual Style**

  This picture is the weird problem.
  Style works well and is displayed like the above picture sometimes, but the other times, like the below picture, it does not work.
  The weird thing is that every time I reload the app without editing my code, Style's appearance sometimes changes. This is the meaning of "Style does not work stably".

  > NOTE: This picture looks different a bit from the above picture like the button color. Please don't care about details because this is just a developing view.

  [image: IMG_4291 Medium]
- **What I did for fixing the problem**

  - Clear cache and reload the app
  - Stop using my custom theme
    These does not fix the problem.
- code

Here is my code.
`WordBox` is called by `HomePresenter`.
When `onPress` is emitted, `WordBox` shows.

I'm not familiar with `React Native` and `Expo` very much, so I first faced this problem and am really troubled.
My explanation must be complex because I am not used to use English, but if it is alright with you, please tell me how to fix it.

Thank you.

```
export const WordBox = (isShow: boolean): JSX.Element | null => {
  if (!isShow) {
    return null
  } else {
    return (
      <View width="full" height="full">
        <Center width="full" height="full">
          <Box
            width={sizes.Box.width}
            height={sizes.Box.height}
            backgroundColor={colors.Base.White}
            borderRadius="3xl"
            shadow="7"
          >
            <Text mt="4" fontSize="3xl" fontWeight="bold" textAlign="center">
              Set a new marker here?
            </Text>
            <Button
              fontWeight="bold"
              fontSize="2xl"
              borderRadius="3xl"
              width="28"
              height="10"
            >
              Yes
            </Button>
            <Button
              fontWeight="bold"
              fontSize="2xl"
              borderRadius="3xl"
              width="28"
              height="10"
            >
              No
            </Button>
          </Box>
        </Center>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

---

### Additional Information(Without `NativeBase` code)

I styled my app again without `NativeBase` following great Abe's advise.

This issue still happens.

The minor appearance is different from above pictures a bit, but the view changes when reloading my app or rerunning it like these two pictures because Style doesn't work well.

[image: s]
[image]

Here is my code without using `NativeBase` but using `tailwind-rn` instead.

```
export const WordBox = (isShow: boolean): JSX.Element | null => {
  const tailwind = useTailwind()
  return (
    <View style={tailwind('m-auto bg-white rounded-3xl h-1/6 w-10/12')}>
      <Text style={tailwind('mt-2 text-2xl font-bold text-center')}>
        Set a marker here?
      </Text>
      <View style={tailwind('mt-4 gap-x-2 flex-row justify-center')}>
        <Pressable style={tailwind('rounded-3xl w-7 h-2.5 bg-emerald-600')}>
          <Text style={tailwind('font-bold text-base')}>Yes</Text>
        </Pressable>
        <Pressable style={tailwind('rounded-3xl w-7 h-2.5 bg-emerald-600')}>
          <Text style={tailwind('font-bold text-base')}>No</Text>
        </Pressable>
      </View>
    </View>
  )
}
```

---

### Additional Information(Where `WordBox` is called)

`WordBox` is called inside `MapView` component which is wrapped by `HomePresenter`.
`newmarker` is called when I press on the screen, so `new marker` is not related to this problem, I think.

```
export const HomePresenter: FC<HomeProps> = ({
  loading,
  location,
  newMarker,
  showAddModal,
  onPress,
}) => {
  const tailwind = useTailwind()

  return (
    <View>
      {loading ? (
        <View style={tailwind('text-center justify-center')}>
          <Text style={tailwind('font-bold text-2xl')}>Loading</Text>
        </View>
      ) : (
        <>
          <MapView
            key="mapview"
            provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
            showsUserLocation={true}
            showsMyLocationButton={true}
            style={tailwind('h-full w-full')}
            region={location}
            onPress={(e: MapEvent) => {
              onPress(e)
            }}
          >
            {newMarker && newMarker}
            <WordBox />       // WordBox is called HERE
          </MapView>
        </>
      )}
    </View>
  )
  // }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried making the modal without using NativeBase?  Personally I have had nothing but trouble from component libraries, and the component in your mockup is not too hard to make on your own.  It would be good to eliminate the component library as the source of the issue.

Comment: @Abe Thank you for commenting on my post. You are definitely right so I tried to style my app without `NativeBase`. The problem is still happening unfortunately, so style doesn't work stably.
I am not so sure but this problem may come from `Expo`.
One of ways I come up with is to recreate my project but I honestly don't want to do that. If you know something on this Style problem, I would like you to tell me a way to resolve it.

Comment: Can you post the code you used without NativeBase?

Comment: Thank you for replying it.
I edited my question and added pictures and codes.
When you have time, I would be glad for you to check them.

Comment: Thanks for posting that. I think the appearance of the buttons looks off because the sizes are set too low, if I'm reading the tailwind code right. However, the main issue is the location of the modal content, right? That is pretty odd. With your new code, can you post the screen that the modal is inside? I mainly want to see how the WordBox is positioned and styled in the parent.

Comment: @Abe
Thank you for your great kindness.
I added the parent component on my post.
That code may not be reader-friendly but I would be glad for you to check it.

Honestly, t does not matter to me that buttons look off if the style behavior is the same when reloading my app because I can resolve it by rewriting codes.
I am really wondering why it changes every time I reload...

Comment: Oh! Have you tried moving the modal outside of the MapView? I think only map markers are meant to be children of the MapView. That could explain why it's moving around - the map is trying to match it to a location, maybe.

Comment: @Abe
Thank you for checking it. 
Having placed the modal  is probably the source of this problem as you said!
After I moved `WordBox` underneath `MapView`, the behavior got stable.

And I actually could find [descriptions](https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps#overlaying-other-components-on-the-map) about overlay components on `MapView` thanks to you.
You are really a lifesaver. 
I have no words but thank you.

Comment: You're too kind. Glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this problem thanks to @Abe.

The source of this issue is **placing Modal inside `MapView` component.**
I should've placed my modal underneath `MapView`. In fact, this is written in the [`react-native-maps` Docs](https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps#overlaying-other-components-on-the-map)

I hope those who use `react-native-maps` do not make the same mistakes.